Return Kotlin Flow function with another Flow function from inside a Flow block
I have a function like this:
fun getNumbers2(input: Int): Flow<Int> = callbackFlow {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        send(i + input)
        delay(1000)
    }
    close()
}

I want that Flow to return another Flow from inside a Flow function. How can I achieve something like the following snippet?
fun getNumbers1(): Flow<Int> = callbackFlow {
    val input = 2
    send(input)
    return getNumbers2(input) // do we have any resumeWith() or continueWith() function in Kotlin Flow??
}

The expectation is to achieve a coroutine like this:
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    getNumbers1().collect {
        // it should be able to print results from getNumbers2() as well
        println("Result: $it")
    }
}

I don't want to create a Flow chain like this, because it does not suit my case:
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    getNumbers1().flatMapMerge { getNumbers2(it) }.collect {
        println("Result: $it")
    }
}

Thanks in advance.

Maybe chain flows like this? num1() = flowOf(1).onCompletion { emitAll(f2(1)) }. But you do need to create chain of flows and return it just due to nature of flows being cold - if you don't collect getNumbers1 you won't get input emitted into collector. If you really want to avoid chaining you just do the ugly and end your first function by collect{ send(it) } another flow.

@Pawel I wouldn't call it ugly. This is exactly what I would do to be honest. We can create a handful SendChannel.sendAll(Flow) extension, but I guess this is an overkill.

Use emitAll() in the flow builder:
fun getNumbers1(): Flow<Int> = flow {
    val input = 2
    emit(input)
    emitAll(getNumbers2(input))
}

callbackFlow is more complicated because it is for converting asynchronous listeners into flows.

Thank you. It works on my normal Flow. I just can't find emitAll() or similar function in callbackFlow.

Since callbackFlow currently does not have a function like resumeWith(), continueWith() or emitAll(), so this is my workaround for now:
// you can also use sendAll() as the name for this function, to make it similar with emitAll()
suspend inline fun <E> SendChannel<E>.resumeWith(flow: Flow<E>) {
    flow.collect { send(it) }
    close()
}

I can use this extension function from within a callbackFlow and works as expected:
fun getNumbers1(): Flow<Int> = callbackFlow {
    val input = 2
    send(input)
    resumeWith(getNumbers2(input))
}

BTW, thanks to @Tenfour04 who provided the answer for normal Flow. I wish the Kotlin team will add sendAll() function like emitAll() in normal Flow.
